# mongodb query is very slow for one specific document

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, backend

I have the following database structure for ERP system:
I have a collection for products which are related to a collection for categories,
the relations between two collections are using _id, products are containing the categories ids which are related to.
I have an issue when filtering the products based on specific category which is "super market", the app query still going on without any response until the response time out, however when filtering these products based on another category it works fine, the algorithm to filter products by category name as the following:

```
let category = await Category.findOne({
      $or: [
        { "name.en": { $regex: queries.category, $options: "i" } },
        { "name.ar": { $regex: queries.category, $options: "i" } }
      ]
    })
    if (category) {
      search.categories = { $in: [category._id] };
    }
```

and then find the products that contains the id of found category as the following:

```
let products = await Product.find(search, "", {
            skip: currentProducts,
            limit: limit
          })
```

the process works fine for any category name except the super market category, I am sure that this category is exist and there are products contain it but it still searching without any response until it times out, so what is the problem here?

Also I have a question, in this ERP system the products are global which means that the product may be related to many stores are selling this product with different prices, so I designed the database as the following:
1- collection for stores
2- collection for products contains array of custom prices ids
3- collection for custom prices each document contains the product id and store id and price of the product
The issue here is the database is scaled so now we have more than 40000 product and almost 9 stores for each product selling it so finally we have about 140000 document in custom prices collection, so is this a good thing to design database as this or there is a better design ?
however the way of indexing products is by showing store related products which requires indexing the custom prices collection to find the store prices which makes the query time about 5 ms, so is this good or there is better solution ?, however I am using the native mongodb aggregation and lookups

**Edit**:

This an example of the products collection document:

```
{
"_id": "5dd51c43147001172871c61a",
"status": "approved",
"price": 59.95,
"categories": [
    "5dd51c37147001172871c413",
    "5dd51c37147001172871c414",
    "5dd51c3d147001172871c59d",
    "5dd52a056ceb13168dd5b04a",
    "5dd5b96365a4b415de04f900"
],
"updateState": false,
"stores": [
    "5dde07ec24c64142ceacb851",
    "5dde07ec24c64142ceacb854",
    "5dde07ed24c64142ceacb858",
    "5dde07ee24c64142ceacb866",
    "5dde07ee24c64142ceacb86a",
    "5dde07ef24c64142ceacb86c",
    "5dde07f024c64142ceacb874",
    "5dde07f024c64142ceacb876",
    "5dde1c2b40392b4228a1b9e3"
],
"gallery": [],
"customPrices": [
    "5dde1c2c40392b4228a1bbe8",
    "5dde2ab240392b4228a23cfd",
    "5dde2ab540392b4228a23da9",
    "5dde2ab240392b4228a23d12",
    "5dde2ab640392b4228a23de1",
    "5dde2ab640392b4228a23df2",
    "5dde2ab540392b4228a23db6",
    "5dde2ab240392b4228a23d15",
    "5dde2ab540392b4228a23d9a"
],
"disabled": false,
"deleted": false,
"extras": [],
"createdAt": "2019-11-20T10:58:11.112Z",
"title": {
    "en": "Easy Care Baby Wipes For Sensitive Skin - 80 Wipes Pack Of 21",
    "ar": "ايزي-كير مناديل مبللة للاطفال للبشرة الحساسة - 80 مناديل مبللة عبوة من 21"
},
"image": {
    "name": "/uploads/Carrefour%20Images/477829_0.jpg",
    "path": "/uploads/Carrefour%20Images/477829_0.jpg"
},
"barcode": "477829",
"quantity": 1,
"brand": {
    "en": "",
    "ar": ""
},
"type": "global",
"__v": 0
}
```

and this an example of custom prices collection documents:

```
{
 "_id": "5dda5dd87675c70c6fcce125",
 "price": 59,
 "store": "5dcdb1ffb20788411552596b",
 "product": "5dd68853086f1c37f851c31b",
 "__v": 0
}
```

I made index for the following fields in product collection:

1- title.en
2- title.ar
3- customPrices
4- stores

and created index in customPrices collection for the following field:

1- store
2- product

I observed that regular expression is not working good in some cases, for example when searching using a word + space it takes much time, so please can any one help me in optimizing the performance of the app, as well as the database will be more larger in the short future

Comment: what results do you see if you run an explain plan on the query?

Comment: They are suboptimal queries: unanchored regex means that it can't use an index, using `$or` on two of them is basically two suboptimal queries in one. Skip+limit is also suboptimal since MongoDB needs to page through all the skipped documents before returning the one you want, and all that work just go to waste. I think the schema design need some rethinking.

Comment: I would recommend you to post some example documents, what indexes you are using, and what queries you are doing.

Comment: I did some edits in the post, please revise them and tell me what should I do